# Add a column to the table in nested structure using spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive

I have a hive table with this structure:

```
root
 |-- group: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ord: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user_exps: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- user_variants: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- event_date: string (nullable = true)
```

I have new fields added to the nested structure and I want to write a new field (ord_2) to the table.

```
root
 |-- group: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ord: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ord_2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user_exps: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- user_variants: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- event_date: string (nullable = true)
```

But when I write through pyspark to the table, I get an error:

```
Cannot write extra fields to struct 'group': 'ord_2'
```

I only have access to apache spark sql which works on hive. How do I add a field to a scheme?

Answer (score 2):

Try with [**`withField()`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.withField.html) function from Spark.

**`Example:`**

Now by using **withcolumn** and use **withfield** function to add a nested column `ord_2` to `group` struct.

```
df.withColumn('group', df['group'].withField('ord_2', lit("abc"))).printSchema()
#root
# |-- event_date: string (nullable = true)
# |-- group: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- ord: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- user_exps: array (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
# |    |-- user_variants: array (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
# |    |-- ord_2: string (nullable = false)

df.show()
#+----------+--------------------------------+
#|event_date|group                           |
#+----------+--------------------------------+
#|2023-02-02|{abc, [1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], abc}|
#+----------+--------------------------------+
```